# Using DSUM in Google Sheets to sum recent data

Tags: google-sheets

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet which is populated from a Google Form. The spreadsheet contains the following columns:

- timestamp
- numericValue

I want to be able, to sum up, the numericValue column for all rows that were added in the last 24 hours.

I have tried the following formula on a second sheet:

```
=dsum('Form responses 1'!A:B,"numericValue", Criteria!A1:A2)
```

And on a third sheet (Criteria) have the following in column A:

```
Timestamp
>=now() - 1
```

I always get a count of zero, I assume DSUM isn't parsing my criterion correctly.

Is there another simple way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=SUMIF('Form responses 1'!A:A,>(now()-1),'Form responses 1'!B:B)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sheet2**, cell **A1: `=FILTER(Sheet1!A:B,Sheet1!A1:A < NOW(), Sheet1!A1:A > NOW()-1)`**

**Sheet2**, cell **E1: `=SUM(B1:B)`**

**[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11xLHkN6l0yzyzYFl-572B5CIp9ppJMDAv0IFeZ3_l8U/edit#gid=1716887025)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

one-liner: **`=SUMIFS(Sheet1!B1:B,Sheet1!A1:A,">"&(NOW()-1),Sheet1!A1:A,"<"&(NOW()))`**

**[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dRVtDEChrZ_6J0p-2uJf1GYZ1hsRA1IZhuBfVKLN9Dw/edit#gid=1716887025)**

[image]

---

---

I guess you need this: **[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XonvpHdDwTubkPgRip_W69TxbdXbz5ErqWXWl8vTb_c/edit#gid=1716887025)**

```
=SUMIFS('Form responses'!B1:B,'Form responses'!A1:A,">"&Criteria!A1,'Form responses'!A1:A,"<"&Criteria!A2)
```

where sheet **Criteria** has:

- cell **A1**: **`=(NOW()-1)`**
- cell **A2**: **`=(NOW())`**